# Merging multiple versions of same excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

So here's the situation:

I have multiple versions of the same spreadsheet-- each one has the exact same row and column labels.

The difference between any two given spreadsheets is that data in one spreadsheet shouldn't be in the other (but sometimes it might.)

Is there anyway to merge all of them into a "master copy" (or just a blank version) of the spreadsheet? (basically, using the data from various versions of that worksheet to fill out the main one)

Copy-pasting is extremely tedious, and doesn't allow me to copy blocks of rows IF the row numbering is non-contiguous. (For example, Rows 1, 2, 3, 6 are in a block, but row 4 and 5 just don't exist.)

Ideas? Googling hasn't turned up anything that seemed directly relevant to this problem.

Comment: Is each version in different file?

Comment: @matan129 yes, each version of the spreadsheet is in a different xls file.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001376.htm#1):

> To merge Microsoft Excel files together, it is best to save them as
>   CSV files first. Open the Excel files and in the menu bar, click File,
>   Save As. In the Save as type drop-down list, select CSV (comma
>   delimited) from the list.
>
> Do this for each Excel file you want to merge, then place all the CSV
>   files in the same folder. For ease, place them in a folder in the root
>   of the C: drive (e.g. c:\csvfiles).
>
> Open the Windows command prompt and navigate to the folder containing
>   the CSV files. Type dir to view the files in the folder and ensure all
>   the files are there.
>
> Type in the below command to merge all CSV files in the folder into a
>   new CSV file titled "newfile.csv" (any name could be used).
>
> > copy *.csv newfile.csv
>
> After the new file has been created open the new CSV file in Microsoft
>   Excel and save it as an Excel file.

Comment: I'm also assuming that since csv files are plaintext, I have to do this for each corresponding spread sheet from the different xls files?

Comment: Yes, you will have to save each of the spreadsheets in csv format manually. 
**Edit**: [Here's a handy application for batch converting xls to cs](http://cwestblog.com/2013/04/12/batch-excel-to-csv-converter-application/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this with Excel. If you save as a CSV file, this is very easy to do in [R](http://www.r-project.org/).

```
file1 <- read.csv("file1.csv", header=TRUE, nrows=50000) # read the file into memory
file2 <- read.csv("file2.csv", header=TRUE, nrows=50000)
file3 <- read.csv("file3.csv", header=TRUE, nrows=50000)

merge12 <- merge(file1, file2, all=TRUE)                 # merge the files
final <- merge(merge12, file3, all=TRUE)

write.csv(final, "merged-data.csv", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE) # save the output as CSV
```

Once you have the CSV output, you can import back into Excel, save as XLSX and you're on your way.

On the `read.csv()` statements, `nrows` is a way of limiting the amount of memory allocated to this data. I usually round up to the next 1,000 (so if your file has 1,200 rows, I'd put 2,000). This isn't necessary, but I find it helps with R performance if you're working with a lot of data.

Comment: Ah, matan129's [answer](http://superuser.com/a/614687/84777) is much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring ALL the rows from ALL the files into a single file in any of various ways including simply copying the rows in one after another pasting them into the new spreadsheet (or into the existing one that shall become the master). Once there, and of course, some will be duplicates, obviously, but that's the next step.

Use Excel's remove duplicates functionality. Using the Ribbon menu, Data tab, Data Tools group, locate the Remove Duplicates menu option and click it. Go from there, it's pretty straightforward. Ensure you leave all the columns checked so that only rows that are fully duplicated are removed. Or, of course, if some columns don't matter, they can be unchecked.

Excel will only leave rows that are completely unique for the column set you leave checked.

And now you have what you need, as I read your question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176374)